# Java database connection issue

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following issue with my code :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306" ;
        try{ 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
                { System.out.println("Eroare incarcare driver!\n" + e);
                return; 
                }
        try{ 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        // Golim tabelul persoane 
                String sql = "DELETE FROM persoane"; 
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                stmt.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test");
                stmt.execute("USE test");
```

i get the exception...any idea how i can make this work? thx.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: it`s the exception. Eroare incarcare driver!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Use url as jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB

Comment: add mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar into the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` occured due to "class not found" in your project/war/ear. Exception is very self explanatory, How to solve it.
In your case:

Add `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` driver class/jar in your build/deployment/lib path you can
download it [HERE](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm)

Read here
[Offical](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to download and add the jdbc connector to your classpath.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

to

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
```

and replace it with your`username` and `password`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the MySQL driver on your application [classpath.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)